# Swing UI getting terminate after running it from batch file

Tags: java, swing

I have created a batch for my java swing application.After running batch the UI vanishes in seconds.

How to put my swing UI on hold until and unless we close it manually.

My batch file as below:

```
@echo on 
set PATH=.;%PATH%
set CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
echo "Installing"
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Xms512M -Xmx1G -classpath ./Installer/bin/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=installer.conf %CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER%
pause
```

Comment: Show us your batch code

Comment: Run it from the command line, look for any possible exceptions

Comment: How to run batch file from command prompt?

Comment: The `pause` should already cause a ... `pause` (hence the name), no matter what exceptions are thrown. To start at the command prompt: Change into the directory where the `BAT` file is located, and type the name of the `BAT` file. And... then... press "Enter".

Comment: After running batch file from the command prompt no exceptions are shown and java swing UI appears and vanishes in a second.

Comment: Tyr to add `START` before `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"`

Comment: You just need to invoke the java class which has the main method and which creates your Frame from the batch file

Comment: ortis i tried to add START and after running batch file i got the following error "The system cannot find the file -Xms512M"

Comment: S.B i have a main class named as MainRunner.java and from this class i am calling a class (Run.java) which extends JFrame

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Comment: S.B no still stuck on same error

Comment: Can you post your code sample MainRunner.java and Run.java?

Comment: Actually i am developing a maven project and within that project i am using swing for UI.so do i need to add any dependency for swing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below and see:

- Set the classpath to include the dependent jars if any and the location of the class files(bin folder)
- set java home
- execute the Main Class(with the main() method, com/main being the package name,change it according to your package structure)

Sample batch file:

```
@echo on 
For /F  "delims=" %%i in ('cd') Do set currentdir=%%i
SET CLASSPATH=%currentdir%\bin;%currentdir%\lib\poi-3.9.jar;
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
SET path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%path%;
java com/main/MainRunner
pause
```

Check if this helps.